The client side doesnt recognizes the cors from a dart server
I have been working in a project with Flutter. Everything its working in Flutter for Android&Ios plataform. But in web version the server side needs to use cors.
I made a backend dart application and use this method:
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';

class MiddlewareInterception{
  static Middleware get contenTypeJson => createMiddleware(
    responseHandler: (Response res) => res.change(
      headers: {
        'content-type' : 'application/json',
        'xpto': '123',
      },
    )
  );

  static Middleware get cors{
    // habilitar acesso para qualquer origem
    final headersPermitidos = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
      };

    Response? handlerOption(Request req){
      if(req.method == 'OPTIONS'){

          return Response(200, headers: headersPermitidos);
      }
    
    else{
        return null;
    }
    }


    Response addCorsHeader(Response res) => res.change(headers: headersPermitidos);

    return createMiddleware(
      requestHandler: handlerOption,
      responseHandler: addCorsHeader,
    );
  }
}



My server main function:
var cascadeHandler = Cascade()
    .add(PendencyApi(pendencyService).handler)
    .add(LoginApi(loginService).handler)
    .handler;

  final handler = Pipeline()
  .addMiddleware(logRequests())
  .addMiddleware(MiddlewareInterception.contenTypeJson)
  .addMiddleware(MiddlewareInterception.cors)
  .addHandler(cascadeHandler);

 
  final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080');
  final server = await serve(handler, ip, port);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');

But when i use from Cors tester, flutter web dont work:

The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer. This indicates an error which most likely cannot be solved by the library.

I have tried:

shelf_cors_headers too but same issue.
specify allow origin


Try * instead of https://localhost . It looks like you are using HTTP (not HTTPS) - as you are using port 8080. As you are using HTTP, grab a packet capture and check the request/response on the wire.

@RichardHeap I'll try wireshark, I think its something in shelf configuration because I used another framework and cors worked normally
